# How do I avoid down-casting to the interface class?

Tags: vba, excel, inheritance, casting

I'm using Excel VBA (Excel 2010) and I've run into a problem when attempting to use inheritance. Basically, I have an interface `MyInterface` and an implementing class `MyImplementation`. In the VBA code, when I refer to a `Dim` of type `MyInterface` I can only access members defined on that interface - *this is expected*. When I refer to a `Dim` of type `MyImplementation` I cannot access members defined on the interface it implements - *not expected*.

Why can I not call the interface property **directly** on the implementation class?

**MyInterface**

```
Option Explicit

Public Property Get Text() As String
End Property
```

**MyImplementation**

```
Option Explicit
Implements MyInterface

'The implementation of the interface method'
Private Property Get MyInterface_Text() As String
  MyInterface_Text = "Some Text"
End Property

Public Property Get MoreText() As String
  MoreText = "Yes, some more text!"
End Property
```

**MainModule - usage examples**

```
Function Stuff()
  Dim impl As New MyImplementation
  Dim myInt As MyInterface: Set myInt = impl
  'The following line is fine - displays "Yes, some more text!"
  MsgBox impl.MoreText
  'This is also fine - displays "Some text"
  MsgBox DownCast(impl).Text
  'This is also fine - displays "Some text"
  MsgBox myInt.Text
  'This is *not* fine - why??
  MsgBox impl.Text
End Function

Function DownCast(ByRef interface As MyInterface) As MyInterface
  Set DownCast = interface
End Function
```

The main question is how can I avoid down-casting?

Note - the example above is intentionally contrived. I realize it's *generally* bad practice to refer directly to implementation classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When I refer to a Dim of type MyImplementation, I cannot access members defined on the interface it implements - not expected.

The solution is to change your expectation.  That's the way things work in VBA: VBA classes implement COM interfaces (such as IUnknown) without exposing them publicly.

If you want to expose your interface's members from the class, you have to do so explicitly:

```
Option Explicit
Implements MyInterface

'The implementation of the interface method'
Private Property Get MyInterface_Text() As String
    MyInterface_Text = "Some Text"
End Property

Public Property Get MoreText() As String
    MoreText = "Yes, some more text!"
End Property

Public Property Get Text() As String
    Text = MyInterface_Text 
End Property
```

Comment: *The solution is to change your expectation.* - Hehe agreed! WRT your answer, I had seen this solution online. For client code of `MyImplementation` the solution is nice, but for all implementers of `MyInterface` it's not. If I have 10 properties on my interface and 10 implementation classes, that's 100 methods I have to write!! This seems rather unmaintainable in the long term. Anyhow, you hit the nail on the head: I need to change my expectations! Thanks for the answer - accepted!

Comment: Quick question: do you happen to know if VB.NET requires the same technique? Or does it work as per my original expectation?

Comment: No VB.NET doesn't have this restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare the implementing methods as Public instead of Private will do:

```
Option Explicit
' Class MyImpl
Implements MyInterface

'The implementation of the interface method'
'Notice the Public here instead of private'
Public Property Get MyInterface_Text() As String
    MyInterface_Text = "Some Text"
End Property
```

The only thing to keep in mind is that to invoke the methods on the implementation you'll need to use a longer name:

```
Dim instance as MyImpl
 ' initialize your instance
instance.MyInterface_Text 
' instead of instance.Text
```

That's all.